# AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant when attempting to post data to Google Maps Engine API using Google's API Client Library for Python

Tags: python, google-maps, python-2.7

I'd like to build a custom Google Map using Google Maps Engine API. To do this I need to post some data to the Google Maps Engine API. I'm trying to use Google API Client Library for Python to create a `OAuth 2.0` flow object to get the necessary permission to allow me to post my data to the Google Maps API but I get an `AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant` raised when I attempt to execute my request.

Here's my code:

```
import httplib2
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run

with open('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\client_id.txt') as f:
    client_id = f.read()
with open('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\client_secret.txt') as f:
    client_secret = f.read()
with open('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\api_key.txt') as f:
    api_key = f.read()


scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsengine'
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, scope)
storage = Storage('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()

credentials = run(flow, storage) #Opens my browser asking me to sign in with a Google account

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('mapsengine', 'v1', developerKey=api_key, http=http)
table = service.tables()
request = table.files().insert(id='11', filename='C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\GitHub\\Turf_project\\df_json', media_body=None)
response = request.execute()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AccessTokenRefreshError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-698f94a34d91> in <module>()
----> 1 response = request.execute()

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.pyc in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    130         else: # IGNORE
    131           pass
--> 132       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    133     return positional_wrapper
    134 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\apiclient\http.pyc in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    714 
    715       resp, content = http.request(str(self.uri), method=str(self.method),
--> 716                                    body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
    717       if resp.status < 500:
    718         break

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.pyc in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    130         else: # IGNORE
    131           pass
--> 132       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    133     return positional_wrapper
    134 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.pyc in new_request(uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
    492       if resp.status in REFRESH_STATUS_CODES:
    493         logger.info('Refreshing due to a %s' % str(resp.status))
--> 494         self._refresh(request_orig)
    495         self.apply(headers)
    496         return request_orig(uri, method, body, clean_headers(headers),

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.pyc in _refresh(self, http_request)
    661           self._updateFromCredential(new_cred)
    662         else:
--> 663           self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
    664       finally:
    665         self.store.release_lock()

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.pyc in _do_refresh_request(self, http_request)
    708       except StandardError:
    709         pass
--> 710       raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
    711 
    712   def _revoke(self, http_request):

AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
```

Could somebody explain why I get this error even though I've logged in with my Google Account?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a real simple and almost nosense but has worked for me many times...
Check that your date-time is synced via NTP with Google and voila! Could be fixed....